# Assign string with spaces to variable and escape those spaces

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to get some json data using `jq`:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "title": "This is a title",
        "description": "Just a description"
    }
}
```

by running `jq -r '.meta | .title, .description' ./project.json`, which gives me the expected result:

```
This is a title
Just a description
```

Now I need to assign the content to a variable in my bash script:

```
read TITLE DESCRIPTION < <(echo $(jq -r '.meta | .title, .description' ./project.json))
```

But this is not working because of the spaces. Also later I have to escape all spaces, which I would do with:

```
echo ${TITLE// /\\ }
```

How should I handle the assignment of the variable (handling space content) and escape the spaces (maybe in one step)?

Comment: If you need to escape spaces in your data, you're Doing It Wrong. Escaping is only required when data is substituted into code, and you shouldn't ever do that.

Comment: Ì suppose you  should just write a script like this in javascript or in Python: you are walking miles to do what are actually trivial steps in json processing, and this is just in this one line of code.

Comment: Also, all-caps variable names are in reserved space used by variables that reflect or modify behavior of the shell itself -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, reserving variables with at least one lowercase character in their names for application use. (That specification is talking about environment variables, but setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so you can't follow the spec for one type without following it for both).

Comment: @jsbueno, the miles are being walked unnecessarily. It doesn't need to be this hard in bash either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to escape anything here.

Using NULs to delimit all values, so we can correctly support titles or descriptions that contain newlines:

```
{
  IFS= read -r -d '' title
  IFS= read -r -d '' description
} < <(jq -r '.meta | (.title, .description) | (., "\u0000")' )
```

---

If we assume that `title` and `description` cannot contain literal newlines, either of the below will do:

```
{
  IFS= read -r title
  IFS= read -r description
} < <(jq -r '.meta | .title, .description' ./project.json)
```

...or, telling `read` to look for a terminating NUL, and thereby ensuring that it has a nonzero exit status should `jq` fail (but still using a newline to separate the two values):

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' title description < <(
  jq -r '.meta | (.title, .description, "\u0000")' ./project.json
)
```

---

Taking advantage of jq's support for generating `sh`-compatible eval-safe escaping, we can also do the following, which *does* correctly handle strings with newlines:

```
eval "$(jq -r '
  .meta | "description=\(.description|@sh); title=\(.title|@sh)"
' ./project.json)"
```

Comment: I will use the data in the next command which looks like `docker run ... --build-arg TITLE=${TITLE}` and here all spaces have to be escaped

Comment: @user3142695, no, they don't. `--build-arg TITLE="$TITLE"` (or if you follow this instruction, `--build-arg TITLE="$title"`) -- the double quotes suppress word-splitting.

Comment: @user3142695, putting escapes in your data doesn't actually work; escapes are _syntax_, not data. See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @user3142695, ...if data were parsed as syntax, it would be impossible to write secure code handling untrusted data in shell languages. Thankfully, data and syntax are two different things, so data including things like `$(rm -rf ~)` is harmless, and backslashes inside data are meaningless to the shell unless you write sloppy/insecure code that substitutes that data into contexts where it's parsed as syntax.

Comment: @user3142695, if you have problems with `docker --build-arg TITLE="$TITLE"` where `TITLE` is a variable that contains whitespace without literal escape characters present in the data, I'd _love_ to see a separate question with a [mre] demonstrating those problems, and would be glad to answer it (albeit not right now, about to leave for lunch). Needing literal escapes in data is a "code smell" -- it indicates something that consumes that data is likely following practices that make it vulnerable to shell injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

With builtin `mapfile`, `bash` and an array (title):

```
mapfile -t title < <(jq -r '.meta | .title, .description' project.json)
echo "${title[0]}"
echo "${title[1]}"
```

Output:

```
This is a title
Just a description
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some parameter substitutions:

```
$ x=$(jq ... )
$ title="${x%$'\n'*}"
$ description="${x#*$'\n'}"
$ typeset -p title description
declare -- title="This is a title"
declare -- description="Just a description"
```